# Missing processes in ps output?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I've seen some unknown processes in top (Ubuntu 22.04) - for example reader#0, reader#1 etc.
These are parts of collectd,  I can't find them in the output of `ps eax` or `ps -eLF` or `ps -eHF`, but I found them in directory /proc... The ps commands were run as root.
In some variations (for example `ps -eTF`) I can find the pid of these processes as spid of collectd, but the process doesn't appear.
Could you tell me why are these processes hidden from ps (but shown in top)?

```
root        1854    1893       1  0 216128 13492  0 júl21 ?       00:00:09 /usr/sbin/collectd
root       32320   32320   30290  0  5189  2788   3 19:34 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 1893
root:~# ls -ld /proc/1893
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 júl   22 19:08 /proc/1893
root:~# cat /proc/1893/cmdline 
/usr/sbin/collectd
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know these things you see in `top` are threads of `collectd` process. So with `ps` you see the process only. Check with command:

```
ps -eflT
```

(`-T` is the key for threads)

and I think you will see also threads